# Python memory leak: do I need to delete?

Tags: python, memory-leaks, matplotlib

I've got a python script that is slowly consuming all of my memory (48GB).  If I recall, python will perform garbage collection so there is no need for me to cleanup after myself?

for example:

```
class data_store:
    dat1={}
    dat2={}
    dat3={}

class myclass ():

    def mem_func(self):
        self.x = data_store()
        self.x.dat1 = (lots of data)
        self.x.dat2 = (lots of data)
        y = x.dat1 + 1

...
```

Most of my data is stored in data_store() temporarily before it is written out to files.  I would think that this would be the source of the leak.  Everytime mem_func() is called a new data_store() object is created and assigned to self.x.  I assume that the old data_store() object would now be a candidate for the GC to delete.  In addition, I would assume that y also be able to be deleted after mem_func completes.

The only other thing I can think of is that I am creating figures with matplotlib and saving them to a file.  That is all done in one function but perhaps I need to delete the figure properly.  Also, I have a sqlite db that is open the whole time where I am writing data but that is not alot of data.  The image is much bigger.

Comment: It's hard to examine and talk about code that has an illegal method definition, an illegal addition, and half the code doing something useless (creating class attributes like `data_store.dat1` that will only be overwritten by instance attributes).

Comment: well yes there were some typos in my code which I corrected but I think it gets the general idea across.

Comment: After the edit, you're still defining a method without a `self`, adding `1` to a dictionary, and creating class attributes that will only be overwritten by instance attributes. If this is even close to what your real code looks like, your memory leak is probably caused by some much more fundamental misconception about classes vs. instances or something similar.

Comment: ok I see that I'm confusing the class attributes with instance attributes.  In this case though, everytime I overwrite the instance attributes, I would think that the old object would be deleted by the GC.

Comment: The point is that you haven't shown us a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), you're just asking us to imagine your code and guess what you might be doing wrong. Given that you have fundamental errors like this in your code, I'm guessing that what you're doing wrong is more likely to do with similar fundamental errors than with anything in the example you showed us. But of course that's just a guess, because, again, we have nothing to go on here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remember that GC only collects data that no pointer (variable) is pointing at it. In other words, as long as the memory is accessible via your variables, it won't be collected/freed.

So you need to assing `None` to the variables you don't need any more, or assign new data to the same variable names, if you don't need them any more.

Comment: so in my example, when mem_func() is called, and you get to self.x = data_store(), the GC would be free to clear the old data_store object since there is nothing referencing it anymore.  And when mem_func completes, then GC would be free to clear the y object since it is a local variable.  Right?

Comment: If you don't have multiple instances of `myclass` then yes. Remember that GC can free something only if it's not accessible via __any__ variable in your code.